# Setting a View's Menu Item to a Sub-Menu

Tags: 7, views, routes

I'm using Drupal 7.10 and Views 3.1.

This seems like it should be simple but I can't find an answer. I have a menu structure similar to the following:

```
Main >
    About Us >
        History
        Contact Us
    Members >
        Wiki
        Tasks
```

The problem is that tasks is a view page but I can't seem to add the view to anywhere but a direct child of `Main`, there doesn't seem to be a way to add it so that it is a child of `Members`.

I can simply add a link to the page by adding another menu item but this causes the sub-menu to disappear so that, in this case `Wiki` disappears.

Is the only way to do this to add a block and add that block to a page? Or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, so if I understand correctly you have a View Page that is part of your main site hiearchy (main menu).  Unfortunately you can only assign a View (at least through the View interface) to a particular menu, but not any of the children of that menu.  This should be a feature request in the Views issue tracker.

What you need to do is go edit the Main Menu through Administration -> Structure -> Menus, list links for Main Menu, and then find your Tasks page that was dropped in their (should be on the first level) and re-position it to where you want it in your menu hierarchy.

Comment: Yes you understood correctly and this worked! I'll make a feature request, it just seemed like I was missing something obvious but I guess not.

Comment: No problem.  Thanks for the accept and the upvote.

Comment: Err, nevermind, thanks for the accept but not the upvote :)

Comment: Might as well..